# Problem with exporting plots to .pptx or .docx in R

Tags: r, export

I would be really happy if you advise me how to overcome this problem. I have some plots, for example, this:

```
    ggplot(data, aes(x=AGE, y=CHOLESTEROL, group=SEX))+
    geom_point(size=2, aes(color=SEX))+
    theme_few()+
    geom_smooth(method=lm, se=TRUE,  aes(color=SEX))
```

It looks totally normal. Then I try to export it:

```
    library(export)
    graph2ppt(file="Rplot.pptx", append=TRUE)
```

And receive an empty Rplot.pptx file in the work directory, with an error message:

"Error in zip::unzip(zipfile = newfile, exdir = folder) : zip error:`Cannot open zip file`C:\Users\Annie\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpyeF49H\file283c16956907.pptx`for reading` in file `zip.c:238`

I looked at this folder in the Temp, but didn't find there any zip files, and none zip.c:238 specifically.

I understand that there should be something wrong with the path, but I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: Take a look at `ggsave` function. With it you can easily save ggplots.

Comment: Thank you, it's an alternative, but it doesn't allow saving in pptx. We were recommended to use pptx to be able to ungroup the plot and modify it. Also, the prof on the upcoming exam would be a bit unhappy about it.

Comment: Pptx is power point from Microsoft right? Why would you want a picture as pptx? Sorry i have never saved it as pptx.

Comment: Yes, it's the Microsoft Powerpoint. It allows ungrouping the plot and manually adjusting the elements a bit.